# Single page WordPress theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I made a single page HTML to WordPress website. There are 4 sections and 4  menu items. The section id and menu id are  the same (ordering by page order).

Basically in the HTML format when you click on the menu, the scroll bar automatically goes to the related section. When I turn it into WordPress  everything is working but when I click over the menu it doesn't.

```
<!-- Menu section -->
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-xs-4 main-menu text-right">
    <ul class="menu-first hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <?php
        global $post;
        $args = array('post_type'=>'page','orderby'=>'menu_order','order'=>'ASC');
        $myposts = get_posts($args);

        foreach($myposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);?>
            <li><a href="#<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-menu visible-sm visible-xs"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
</div> <!-- /.main-menu -->

<!-- Service -->
<div class="content-section" id="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="heading-section col-md-12 text-center">
                <h2>Services</h2>
            </div> <!-- /.heading-section -->
        </div> <!-- /.row -->
        <div class="row">
            <?php
            global $post;
            $args = array('post_type'=>'service','orderby'=>'menu_order','order'=>'ASC');
            $myposts = get_posts($args);
            foreach($myposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

             <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="service-item" id="service-1">
                    <div class="service-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-<?php echo $service_icon; ?>"></i>
                    </div> <!-- /.service-icon -->
                    <div class="service-content">
                        <div class="inner-service">
                           <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                           <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- /.service-content -->
                </div> <!-- /#service-1 -->
            </div> <!-- /.col-md-3 -->
            <?php endforeach; ?>

           </div> <!-- /.row -->
    </div> <!-- /.container -->
</div> <!-- /#services -->
```

Related code located also at [paste bin](http://pastebin.com/Yhj81LHX).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any anchors with `name` attributes for your link to actually jump to. Try this:

```
<?php foreach($myposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="service-item" id="service-1">
        <!-- Rest of markup removed for clarity -->
            <h3>
                <a name="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```